# probability of rolling repeated numbers

Tags: statistics, dice, gambling

if you roll an *x*-sided die, *n*-number of times, what are the chances of getting *r*-number of repeated values?

if I roll a twenty-sided die, eighty times, what are the chances that I'll roll a six twice and a sixteen twice? ... but NOT specifically six and sixteen; just any value/s repeated, *two or more* times?

from, say, eight rolls of a twenty-sided die, I get this:
{10,12,8,10,2,5,3,5}

what were the chances of getting those two tens, and two fives, in that many rolls?

and the ACTUAL question I have is: what is the calculation to figure out how many 'repeated values' you should **expect** in *n* rolls of an *x*-sided die?

so far, if I do this:

1 - r * (product from i=0,(n-1) of (x-i)/x)

given the example of rolling two repeats - that is, two fives and two tens - from eight throws of a twenty-sided die, like this {10,12,8,10,2,5,3,5}
I would put this in wolfram

1 - 2 * ( product from i=0,7 of (20-i)/20 )

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1+-+2+*+%28+product+from+i%3D0%2C7+of+%2820-i%29%2F20+%29

and get 'basically 60%'

but how do I figure out the chances of any value repeating two *or more* times, specifically *t*-number of times?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want the probability that, after rolling $n$ $x$-sided dice, there was at least one repeated value? Or do you want the probability distribution that, after having rolled $n$ $x$-sided dice, there were $p$ distinct values that appeared more than once? Or something else?

Comment: after rolling an x-sided die, n times, there were at least r number of repeated values, that repeated t number of times: "chances of rolling two 'triples' in seven throws of a twenty-sided die" ... in wolframalpha code; and not distinct values, just any repeated value/s

Comment: Your *basically 60%* looks wrong.  With $10^5$ simulations of $8$ rolls of a $20$-sided die, I saw about $20\%$ with $0$ repeated values, $49\%$ with $1$, $27\%$ with $2$, $3\%$ with $3$, and a small number with $4$, where "repeated value" means a side appearing twice or more.

Comment: YES - it seems very wrong, doesn't it! I just rolled two doubles in eight throws of a twenty-sided die ... how unlikely is that to have just happened?  I'm not precisely sure how to figure that out; the wolfram code I use would give me 80% chance of getting 1-or-more repeated values - which is close to what you have

Answer (score 1):

### Use combinations and permutations

One option is to follow the patterns in [this blog post](https://asteroid.divnull.com/2008/01/chance-of-reign/) (not mine). An excerpt:

> *Triple and two pair (3x,2x,2x).* Ten ways to select the height of the triple, the dice for which can be chosen C(7,3) ways. There are C(9,2) ways to select the heights of the pairs. The first pair can be selected C(4,2) ways, the second C(2,2). The remaining three die can come up 7 different ways without matching the other sets (note that this is P(7,1)). 10 × C(7,3) × C(9,2) × C(4,2) × C(2,2). For more than seven dice, there would dice left over that could not match the value of any of the sets or each other, so permutations of the seven remaining possible values would be used: 10 × C(n,3) × C(9,2) × C(n−3,2) × C(n−5,2) × P(7,n−7).

(Note that this example uses d10s rather than d20s, but the general principles are there.) It should be possible to derive an algorithm to determine these expressions; however, I have not done so. Rather, I prefer to...

### Use a more general-purpose algorithm

I've created a more general-purpose algorithm as part of my [Icepool Python library](https://github.com/HighDiceRoller/icepool) that can solve many dice pool problems; while a bespoke solution as above is probably more efficient, mine is good enough for pool sizes that you're likely to physically roll. You can read a crude explanation of the algorithm [here](https://gitlab.com/highdiceroller/hdroller/-/wikis/dice%20pool%20algorithm). In short, as long as we can express the pool evaluation as a transition function over (outcome, count) pairs without too large a state space, it's possible to compute the solution reasonably efficiently.

```
import icepool

class AllMatchingSets(icepool.EvalPool):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, count):
        if state is None:
            state = ()
        # If at least a pair, append the size of the matching set.
        if count >= 2:
            state += (count,)
        # Prioritize larger sets.
        return tuple(sorted(state, reverse=True))

all_matching_sets = AllMatchingSets()

# Evaluate on 10d20.
print(all_matching_sets.eval(icepool.Pool(icepool.d20, 10)))
```

You can try it in your browser using [this JupyterLite notebook](https://highdiceroller.github.io/icepool/notebooks/lab?path=all_matching_sets.ipynb). Just change the d10s to d20s.

Here's an example output for 8d20:

Denominator: 25600000000

| Outcome | Weight | Probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| () | 5079110400 | 19.840275% |
| (2,) | 10939622400 | 42.732900% |
| (2, 2) | 5860512000 | 22.892625% |
| (2, 2, 2) | 781401600 | 3.052350% |
| (2, 2, 2, 2) | 12209400 | 0.047693% |
| (3,) | 1562803200 | 6.104700% |
| (3, 2) | 1041868800 | 4.069800% |
| (3, 2, 2) | 97675200 | 0.381544% |
| (3, 3) | 32558400 | 0.127181% |
| (3, 3, 2) | 1915200 | 0.007481% |
| (4,) | 130233600 | 0.508725% |
| (4, 2) | 48837600 | 0.190772% |
| (4, 2, 2) | 1436400 | 0.005611% |
| (4, 3) | 1915200 | 0.007481% |
| (4, 4) | 13300 | 0.000052% |
| (5,) | 6511680 | 0.025436% |
| (5, 2) | 1149120 | 0.004489% |
| (5, 3) | 21280 | 0.000083% |
| (6,) | 191520 | 0.000748% |
| (6, 2) | 10640 | 0.000042% |
| (7,) | 3040 | 0.000012% |
| (8,) | 20 | 0.000000% |

#### Improving efficiency for more specific queries

If you have a more specific query than enumerating all possible sets of matching sets, you can reduce the state space and improve efficiency by only retaining enough information to compute the answer. For example, if you just want to know the number of pairs:

```
class NumPairs(icepool.EvalPool):
    def next_state(self, state, outcome, count):
        return (state or 0) + (count // 2)

num_pairs = NumPairs()

# Evaluate on 80d20.
print(num_pairs.eval(icepool.Pool(icepool.d20, 80)))
```

| Outcome | Probability |
| --- | --- |
| 30 | 0.000190% |
| 31 | 0.036113% |
| 32 | 0.921689% |
| 33 | 7.379965% |
| 34 | 24.005873% |
| 35 | 35.239404% |
| 36 | 24.047867% |
| 37 | 7.405807% |
| 38 | 0.926534% |
| 39 | 0.036366% |
| 40 | 0.000192% |

(This counts e.g. a quadruple as two pairs---if you want unique pairs just replace `//` with `>=`.)